# tableView wierd behaviour while pushing in navigation controller

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am having some issue while pushing a `viewController` in `UINavigationcontroller` .

What i have is , a `UITabBar` and when click on the button it loads new `viewController` in `UITabBar's` `UINavigationcontroller` .

[image: the last one is the <code>viewController</code> i am pushing in <code>UITabBar</code>'s navigation controller]

I am using this to push it ...

```
 UIStoryboard * storyboard = self.storyboard;
    loginEmailinviteViewController * detail = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginEmailInvite"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController: detail animated: YES];
```

Every thing is perfect but the only problem occurs in `tableview` which looks wierd there . It takes some space above its starting point as if it is on `navigation bar` .

[image]

Please check and help me .

Thanks

Comment: What's the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view did load add following line :

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another tricks,,

In Your Story Board,

1. Drag View Controller
2. Embed with Navigation Controller
3. Drag Table View [Not Table View Controller] and put in View Controller
4. Check the Table View's **Y** position in **Size Inspector**
5. If it shows **64 or anything**, change to **0**
6. Drag Table View Cell and put in Table View
7. Cell will not get down.